# How to make the code work without completionhandler for UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios8

I have used completionhandler for UIActivityViewController, but with ios8 completionhandler has been deprecated.
I get into an infinite loop when i click on automatically created more icon and try to dismiss it without any action.

Comment: You ask how to make the code work, but then don't show any code. Could you copy and paste the relevant bits of code into your question?